# exercise package: Cannot change first question number

Tags: numbering, counters, exercises

I know I can change a question number with `\setcounter{Question}`:

```
\begin{Exercise}[title={Title}, label=opg]
    \Question
    Exercise 1
    \setcounter{Question}{10}
    \Question
    Exercise 11
    \subQuestion
    subQuestion a
    \setcounter{subQuestion}{3}
    \subQuestion
    subQuestion d
\end{Exercise}
```

[image]

But I cannot change the first question's number with the same way:

```
\begin{Exercise}[title={Title}, label=opg]
    \setcounter{Question}{10}
    \setcounter{subQuestion}{3}
    \Question
    Not Exercise 11 ???
    \subQuestion
    Not subQuestion d ???
\end{Exercise}
```

[image]

How can I change the first question's number?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a new exercise is initialized the counters are set to 0, apparently the first `\Question` command triggers this initialization.

As a workaround you can change the definition of the command `\QuestionNB`, which normally prints the value of the `Question` counter, to do three things:

1. Print your desired value
2. Set the counter to that value
3. Change the definition back to the original that prints the value of the counter

In code:

```
\gdef\QuestionNB{%
#1.\ %                                    print the desired value
\setcounter{Question}{#1}%                set the counter
\gdef\QuestionNB{\arabic{Question}.\ }%   change the definition back to the original
}
```

Note that you modify the definition of the command from within the command itself, this is allowed in LaTeX and can be used for situations where you want the first call to a command to do something different than the second and further calls.

The same workaround can be used for `subQuestion`, note that you need `\@alph` for printing the first letter because the regular `\alph` needs a real counter. This can be simplified if you provide the actual value to be printed (`d` instead of `4`), then you can just print `#1`.

Both cases are wrapped in a command that takes the desired value as argument.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\newcommand{\setquestionnr}[1]{%
\gdef\QuestionNB{#1.\ %
\setcounter{Question}{#1}%
\gdef\QuestionNB{\arabic{Question}.\ }%
}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setsubquestionnr}[1]{%
\gdef\subQuestionNB{\@alph{#1})\ %
\setcounter{subQuestion}{#1}%
\gdef\subQuestionNB{\alph{subQuestion})\ }%
}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}[title={Title}, label=opg]
    \setquestionnr{11}
    \setsubquestionnr{4}
    \Question
    Not Exercise 11 ???
    \subQuestion
    Not subQuestion d ???
    \subQuestion
    Second subquestion
    \Question
    Next question
    \subQuestion
    Next subquestion
\end{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]